# Changing background color in an NSCell cell not using NSTextFieldCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscell, nstextfieldcell

At the Moment in my table i have four columns. Three are NSTextFieldCells and one is a custom cell using NSCell. I need to change the color of a row. I've changed color of the NSTextFieldCells but now i need to change the NSCell background color, is there a way to do that? I absolutely cannot use a NSTextFieldCell to do this one cell.